# Problems with Windows EC2 snapshots

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am getting serious access problems every single time I take a Windows snapshot from the EC2 console. After taking the snapshot neither the original machine, nor the images snapshot, are avaialable. And by this I mean that there is no RDP, HTTP or HTTPS connectivity, all of which were accessible ports before the snapshot. There is nothing to explain why this error occurs, as the sys logs are either blank or seem to show a successful snapshot and machine launch. Note that I have also had scenarios where I reboot the machine and again NOTHING is available.

What am I doing wrong? These are the steps I take.

1) Launch a default Win2k8 with IIS7 image. This is my machine: ami-c5e40dac

2) Install .NET 4.0

3) Activate the database (turn on the service).

4) Install my application and the database. This include an HTTPS certificate (I think I read somewhere that Windows has a restart problem if a cert is in the machine store - WTF?)

5) Take a snapshot or reboot --- Bang, everything is dead!

Anyone come across such problems?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem earlier this week; it turned out that my instance was just taking an age to boot (1 hour +).

Is it possible that you had some pending windows updates that wanted to run on startup?